# pay on arrival in Django Oscar?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

So I customized Django-oscar, everything works fine until the payment step

```
Enter payment details
This page needs implementing within your project. You may want to use one of Oscar's payment gateway libraries:

django-oscar-paypal
django-oscar-datacash
django-oscar-gocardless
django-oscar-paymentexpress
django-oscar-accounts
Continue
```

I do not want online payment, my courier will send the package and collect fees. Is it possible to config django-oscar to accept pay-on-arrival style of payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checkout, you have to provide form page for Billing address.

inside apps/checkout/view.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from oscar.apps.checkout import views
from oscar.apps.payment import forms, models

class PaymentDetailsView(views.PaymentDetailsView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Override method so the billing address forms can be
        # added to the context.
        ctx = super(PaymentDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['billing_address_form'] = kwargs.get(
            'billing_address_form', forms.BillingAddressForm())
        return ctx

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Override so we can validate the bankcard/billingaddress submission.
        # If it is valid, we render the preview screen with the forms hidden
        # within it.  When the preview is submitted, we pick up the 'action'
        # parameters and actually place the order.
        if request.POST.get('action', '') == 'place_order':
            return self.do_place_order(request)
        billing_address_form = forms.BillingAddressForm(request.POST)
        if not all([billing_address_form.is_valid()]):
            # Form validation failed, render page again with errors
            self.preview = False
            ctx = self.get_context_data(billing_address_form=billing_address_form)
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)
        # Render preview with bankcard and billing address details hidden
        return self.render_preview(request, billing_address_form=billing_address_form)

    def do_place_order(self, request):
        billing_address_form = forms.BillingAddressForm(request.POST)
        if not all([billing_address_form.is_valid()]):
            messages.error(request, "Invalid submission")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checkout:payment-details'))
        submission = self.build_submission()
        submission['payment_kwargs']['billing_address'] = billing_address_form.cleaned_data
        return self.submit(**submission)
```

Comment: You have 1 missed `(` char in `ctx=self.get_context_databilling_address_form=billing_address_form)` line.

Comment: but why...collect the billing address only after everything is almost finished? isnt it that you normally collect it on the same page (or just after) as the shipping address?